# Trouble with pop-up location in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, window.open

Quick overview of what I am trying to accomplish.  I want to be able to open two popups from one button click on a webpage. I would like the popups to be one thin popup across the entire screen, and one popup underneath across the entire screen and filling the remaining height.  The problem that I have is that my code is only working for Chrome, not firefox or IE.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>PopupTest</title>
<button onclick="infoPopup()">Open</button>
<script>
function infoPopup(){

        var WindowADimensions = ("width="+screen.width+",height=100");
        WindowA = window.open("", "WindowA", WindowADimensions);
        WindowA.moveTo(0,0);
        WindowA.document.write("info here:");

        var WindowBDimensions =          ("scrollbars=1,width="+screen.width+",height="+(screen.height-100));
        WindowB = window.open("", "WindowB", WindowBDimensions);
        WindowB.moveBy(0,100);
        WindowB.location="https://www.google.com";
}
</script>
</html>
```

In chrome it is working just as I want it, opens the two popups in the correct location.  However in Firefox and IE it is opening both popups and placing them in the top left of the screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered just using normal HTML elements for this? You get a lot more control.

Comment: Fat chance of even _opening_ two popups, considering popup and ad blockers; even fatter chance of getting them to look and positioned as you want, with today's tabbed browsing interfaces. (Not to even mention non-desktop devices, if accessibility via those should be any concern at all.) Forget it. Go look into what nice things you can do with modals, which several of the popular JS/CSS libraries offer support for in one form or another.